# Talking about ideas: "slow change of mind/slowly changing her mind"

Tags: verbs, gerunds, infinitives, verb-forms

I'm trying to understand how to write a sentence about someone who change her idea over a topic, because of what a guy tells her over time.

But I'm really not sure how to correctly write this:

> Her *searching* of "strong opinions" drags her into a *slow change of* mind

maybe it would be more appropriate to say:

> Her *searching* of "strong opinions" drags her into *slowly changing her* mind

I'm also wondering if using "searching" instead of "search" is correct, [here](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_infinitive-ing.htm) it says that if it's a subject it should be an -ing form.

Thank you kindly for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Her searching of 'strong opinions' drags her into a slow change of mind"

and,

> "Her searching of 'strong opinions' drags her into slowly changing her mind"

are both grammatically correct, but I think you might want to consider changing the phrasing, if I understand you correctly, to something like this.

> "Her seeking out of strong [or, "radical"?] opinions has slowly changed her mind over time."

Is that what you mean? There is nothing wrong with the ways you have written it.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I mean, and indeed your phrasing is better. Now that I read yours, mine feels so awkward!

Comment: I respect and admire you for learning English. It is a difficult language, even for native speakers. Best wishes.